# Condicion elif no se cumple

Tags: python, condiciones, else

Por alguna razon, cuando el usuario proporciona el valor de True a la hora de preguntar si el envio es gratuito o no, el IF si funciona y a la hora de imprimir los detalles del libro se imprime "El envio es gratuito", pero si el usuario proporciona False como respuesta, solamente se imprime "False" en vez de "El envio no es gratuito"

```
id = int(input("Proporcione el ID del libro: "))
precio = float(input("Proporcione el precio del libro: "))
envioGratuito = input("Indique si el envio es gratuito (True/False): ")

if envioGratuito == "True":
    envioGratuito = True
elif envioGratuito == "False":
    envioGratuito == False
else:
    envioGratuito = "Valor invalido, debe ser True/False"

print("Nombre:", nombre)
print("ID:", id)
print("Precio:", precio)

if envioGratuito == True:
    print("El envio es gratuito")
elif envioGratuito == False:
    print("El envio no es gratuito")
else:
    print(envioGratuito)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en esta línea:

```
envioGratuito == False
```

Estas haciendo una comparación que retorna True/False y que no guardas en ninguna parte.

La línea correcta es una asignación:

```
envioGratuito = False
```

Answer (score 0):

A parte de que tienes un typo, pues tienes una comparación en vez de una asginación, te estás complicando de más. Podrías reducir tu código a:

```py
id = int(input("Proporcione el ID del libro: "))
precio = float(input("Proporcione el precio del libro: "))
envioGratuito = input("Indique si el envio es gratuito (True/False): ")

print("Nombre:", nombre)
print("ID:", id)
print("Precio:", precio)

if envioGratuito == "True":
    print("El envio es gratuito")
elif envioGratuito == "False":
    print("El envio no es gratuito")
else:
    print("Valor invalido, debe ser True/False")
```

Aunque te sugeriría usar (Y/N) en vez de (True/False) pues es más largo. Y bueno, con ignoreCase